# can ng-change and ng-click be used along side with a single button?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

I have a button in my application which works for `ng-click` for now..... I need to insert a functionality to the button as such it should be notified when the content of the table is changed by inputting some values while editing the table

Can I use `ng-click` along with `ng-change`.... How can I relate the `ng-change` of the table with the button?

```
 <button type="button" ng-disabled="vm.currentYear === vm.endYear" 
         ng-attr-title="{{vm.currentYear === vm.endYear ? 'You\'ve reached the ending year for '+ vm.selectedProjectName : 'Load baselines for ' + (vm.currentYear+1)}}" 
         class="btn btn-outlined  " ng-click="vm.changeYear(vm.currentYear+1)" 
         ng-model="baseline.data[$index]" 
         ng-change="vm.enableSaveButton($parent.$parent.$index, $parent.$index, $index, baseline)">
           <i class="fa fa-caret-right"></i>
 </button>
```

Comment: I don't think `ng-change` works with `button`.

Comment: I do kind off agree....then how will i relate a table values edited(changed) with the button?@SaiUnique

Comment: You can use `ng-click`. Why you want to bind change event to button?

Comment: i want to add a ng-bootbox(kind off popup)to the button when the values of the table are modified and button is being clicked on that situation ...How can i do that?@SaiUnique

Comment: i think you can bind $watch on your table content and when ever table content change $watch will work and you can also call your ng-click function in it.

Comment: As @HaiderAli said, you need to `$watch` the data to accomplish that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ng-change work with `input` tag only.  And ng-change require ng-model.

```
 <input type="text" ng-model="test" ng-change="seeChange()" />
```

> Evaluate the given expression when the user changes the input. The
>   expression is evaluated immediately, unlike the JavaScript onchange
>   event which only triggers at the end of a change (usually, when the
>   user leaves the form element or presses the return key).

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange

Comment: How can i bind a change values(of the table)to the button.....i want to add a ng-bootbox(kind off popup)to the button when the values of the table are modified and button is being clicked on that situation ...How can i do that?@Manikandan Velayutham

Comment: use $watch expression.. It will help. go through $watch. Use as per your scenario.

Comment: See basic.. https://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-the-basics-of-scope-watch

Comment: https://www.bennadel.com/blog/2566-scope-watch-vs-watchcollection-in-angularjs.htm

Comment: You can use $watchCollection()

Comment: Thank you..:)@ Manikandan Velayutham...im trying with that

Comment: Welcome.. @HKI345..Just comment here while you got solution.